# Notification color changes when stopForeground is called

Tags: android, exoplayer2.x

I am using `exoplayer` to build an Audio player. When my audio player starts I attach a notification with it. When the player is paused/stopped using the notification pause button, notification background color changes. Here is the test code.

I tried setting the notification color again on `playerNotificationManger` when `stopForeground(false)` is called but no help.

```
            if (it == StreamState.STOPPED) {
                this.stopForeground(false)
            }

            else if (it == StreamState.STARTED) {
                    val channelId = "media_playback_channel"
                    exoNotificationListener = ExoNotificationListener(onNotificationPosted, onNotificationCancelled)
                    playerNotificationManager = playerNotificationManager ?: PlayerNotificationManager.createWithNotificationChannel(
                        application.applicationContext,
                        channelId,
                        R.string.media_playback_notification,
                        R.string.media_playback_notification_id,
                        mcNotificationManager,
                        exoNotificationListener
                    )
                    playerNotificationManager?.setFastForwardIncrementMs(0)
                    playerNotificationManager?.setRewindIncrementMs(0)
                    playerNotificationManager?.setUseNavigationActions(false)
                    // Here I am setting the color which works fine when content is playing.
                    playerNotificationManager?.setColor(notificationColor)
                    bindPlayer(playerNotificationManager)
            }
```

When I start the playback again, the notification color comes back again. I do not want the notification color to change when stopForeground happens.
Can you please suggest what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got it, I had to attach the mediaSession to it. Looking at below blog post here helped me.
https://medium.com/google-exoplayer/the-mediasession-extension-for-exoplayer-82b9619deb2d

Updated code:

```
    val session = MediaSessionCompat(application.applicationContext, channelId)
    val connector = MediaSessionConnector(session)
    connector.setPlayer(exoPlayer)
    playerNotificationManager?.setMediaSessionToken(session.sessionToken)
```

Actually this docs helped me:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder#setcolorized
Set whether this notification should be colorized. When set, the color set with setColor(int) will be used as the background color of this notification.

This should only be used for high priority ongoing tasks like navigation, an ongoing call, or other similarly high-priority events for the user.

For most styles, the coloring will only be applied if the notification is for a foreground service notification.

However, for MediaStyle and DecoratedMediaCustomViewStyle notifications that have a media session attached there is no such requirement.

Calling this method on any version prior to O will not have an effect on the notification